# Using INSERT INTO & UPDATE at the same time - JAVA SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, insert-update

I have a question.

So I have a add functionality where the user can add cars to the database. How do I do a check whilst adding the car, so that if the car does exist-the data is overwritten, instead of an error messaging like 'Duplicate error' appearing?

So I have...

```
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES (1, "AUDI R8", 10);
```

How do I do it so that if a user inputs      (1, "BMW X5, 15), it overwrites the current data?

How would I have an INSERT INTO and UPDATE STATEMENT at the same time? Also how do I make use of transactions here?

Many thanks

Comment: Unless you can maintain some kind of internal reference to the origin of the `Car` record (like the row identifier), you would have to do a `SELECT` first

Comment: Take a look at [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Don't give the users the ability to explicitly `INSERT`/`UPDATE` rows - give them an application that handles car entry creation/maintenance.  Then you can have your application handle this.  Why do you want to update that row?  What if it was _meant_ to be a new row?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a `REPLACE` statement for this kind of cases:

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted
>
> [...]
>
> `REPLACE` is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It either inserts, or deletes and inserts.

Check the [reference for the `REPLACE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best solution for this problem are the **TRIGGERS**.
Triggers allow you to separate the application layer from the the database.
In your case you need to launch an error, so this is a trigger called "passive", that reacts automatically only if the condition is violated.
Take a look a this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html or various related docs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best solution, but u can do a SELECT first, and after do an UPDATE or a simply INSERT, depends of the case.